# Are the workers summoned by julia -p n supposed to be non-interactive?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, read-eval-print-loop

When running a julia -p nthreads REPL, is this behavior intended?

```
julia> isinteractive()
true

julia> fetch(@spawn isinteractive())
false
```

Comment: It isn't `nthreads` it is `nprocesses`.
the difference is a little subtle, but important. (I'm sure there is another question on the site about difference between threads and processes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
They are not running the REPL.
`isinteractive` checks if you are in REPL (or REPL-like, theoretically) enviroment, where the user is entering code, and then running it.

This is not true for remote workers.
They are not interactive in this sense.
(though they can be interacted with, but so can scripts that wait for user input)